# What is the meaning of "Tampoco las otras hablan si nosotros no les prestamos la voz" in "Los Santos Inocentes"?

Tags: expresiones, significado

This is from Miguel Delibes, "Los Santos Inocentes". Don't try reading the original because it lacks punctuation, and scripts of who's talking and all sorts of things that make it incomprehensible.

Here is a modified context:

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand about the highlighted text. It would also help I you shared how you understand the text. In short, why isn't this just a translation request?

Comment: This is a translation request. Are those not allowed here?

Comment: Translation requests are not allowed however you could show your effort and ask what is you don't understand and then the community will help, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: I do not think this was as simple as a translation of the text or the answer would not have been so detailed.

Comment: @user135711 Please don't mock other members of the community. They are only trying to teach you how to ask great questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose they are talking about the letter H in Spanish. The first character says that the letter H is silent, but the word the character uses is *muda*, which can also be used to refer to a person that cannot speak. That's when Facundo asks what does that mean, because every letter in the alphabet is *muda* (has no voice by itself). That is, letters do not speak, they only represent sounds that WE must utter.

That is what the sentence means: all the other [letters] are also silent, they only have voices when we utter their sounds (lend them their voices).

Comment: Oh! That's what it means! There's a mute girl in the story, and I thought he was somehow referring to her or other people not speaking if we don't pay attention to them. I never would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: @user135711 Glad to help. Note that what you just commented is what Krauss is asking in his comment. You should write in your question what you thought the sentence meant (the bit about the mute girl). Yes, we indeed accept translation or sentece clarification requests, but only if some prior effort is shown to answer your own question. If you don't show some effort on your own to try to understand the sentence, the question may be closed as offtopic.